# Use child array to get count for table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, vue.js

I have some json data. I need to count the number of strings in one of the children then create a table that is grouped by part of the child strings and used the count of specific child strings in the table. Confusing and impossible as it seems, this is what we need.

Honestly, I am barely sure where to even start here. Just displaying the strings correctly was a nightmare.

Here's some example json, I'm using for in loops to get through the levels of json above this, that part works fine:

```
"DataValues": [
 {
    "Key": "Stuff Type",
    "Id": "95492",
    "ComboBoxPairs": [
       {
          "Value": {
             "Key": "3 Gallon",
             "Value": "3 Gallon",
             "ExtraValues": []
          },
          "Children": [
             {
                "Key": "Scan",
                "Id": "93478",
                "Strings": [
                   "DogType:Lab,Age:3,Name:Bowser",
                   "DogType:Lab,Age:5,Name:Dingo",
                   "DogType:Mutt,Age:1,Name:Muttman",
                   "DogType:Weiner,Age:1,Name:Goof",
                   "DogType:Mutt,Age:5,Name:Muttman",
                   "DogType:Puppy,Age:1,Name:Silly",
                   "DogType:Puppy,Age:1,Name:Sammy",
                   "DogType:Puppy,Age:1,Name:Shooter",
                   "DogType:Puppy,Age:1,Name:Doc",
                ]
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "Value": {
             "Key": "1 Gallon",
             "Value": "1 Gallon",
             "ExtraValues": []
          },
          "Children": [
             {
                "Key": "Scan",
                "Id": "93478",
                "Strings": [
                   "DogType:Puppy,Age:1,Name:Wingo",
                   "DogType:Puppy,Age:1,Name:Scrappy",
                   "DogType:Mutt,Age:4,Name:Goober"
                ]
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
 }
]
```

Here's what I need to build:

```
DogType ContainerType   Quantity    Volume
Lab         
        3 Gallon        2           6 Gallon
Mutt            
        1 Gallon        1           1 Gallon
        3 Gallon        2           6 Gallon
Weiner          
        3 Gallon        1           3 Gallon
Puppy           
        1 Gallon        2           6 Gallon
        3 Gallon        4           12 Gallon
```

I am honestly not even sure where to get started

Honestly, I'm not even sure if this is possible? You can see that the table needs to be grouped by part of the string, the DogType. I then need to be able to count how many strings with a certain dog type there are in each ContainerType object, and pass that into the Quantity and ContainerType columns in the table. Then volume is multiplying the Gallon value, which is just text, by the quantity.

I'm sure I need to put more code but I can't even think of how to manage this. There could also be multiple ContainerTypes, this data isn't static.

The data isn't my design but I can't change it, just getting to this point has been a disaster. Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: you need separate tables for each child? Or all in one table?

Comment: @zfrisch all in one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what you need to do is transform some data. Basically change the way a certain data is stored / represented. Now the Strings are in a consistent format, so we can use a combination of string operations to get a key => value store out of it (I am going to use ES6 syntax to simplify boilerplate)

```
let parseString = str => {
    let pairs = str.split(',');
    let obj = {};
    pairs.forEach(pair => {
        pair = pair.split(':');
        obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    });
    return obj;
};
```

This function simply takes one of your strings, "DogType:Lab,Age:3,Name:Bowser" for example, and splits out an object such as `{'DogType': 'Lab', 'Age': 3...}`. Now that we have this, we can start to manipulate and group the data itself (if you're not sure what array.map does, it basically gives a new array after running a function on each of the array's values).

```
let comboBoxPairs = data.ComboBoxPairs.map(comboBoxPair => {
    comboBoxPair.Children = comboBoxPair.Children.map(children => parseString(children));
    return comboBoxPair;
});
```

Now we have replaced the incomprehensible array of strings into an array of objects we can start to group. First we need to figure out a data structure. You're grouping by dog type first, so our object's keys are the Dog's Type. Then we simply need to add each quantity into the dog's type and increment a count each time the quantity is encountered.

```
let dogType = {};
comboBoxPairs.forEach(comboBoxPair => {
    comboBoxPair.Children.forEach(children => {
        if (typeof dogType[children.DogType] === 'undefined') {
             dogType[children.DogType] = {};
        }
        if (typeof dogType[children.DogType][comboBoxPair.Value.Key] === 'undefined') {
             dogType[children.DogType][comboBoxPair.Value.Key] = 0;
        }
        dogType[children.DogType][comboBoxPair.Value.Key]++;
   });
});
```

And you're done! This gives you a Object such as :

```
{
    'Lab': {
        '1 Gallon': 2,
         ....
     },
};
```

You can then loop through this object to display the values and totals.

Comment: Holy cow that looks like it will work! I had tried map and a few other things to get the nonsense array of strings into objects, but then couldn't work with the objects correctly because I kept getting to the key just being an index with the WHOLE STRING as the value. With your solution, I could loop though the object and get what I need. If I was using Vue on the front-end, and just to display. Could I use v-for to loop through it? I can add the code to my original question if it doesn't make sense. We use Vue in the html file to display the returned data, but it works in an odd way.

Comment: @ptrugby4141 yeah, [Vue can loop through objects](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-Object). You can just do ```<div v-for="(value, dogType) in dogTypes"><div v-for="(quantity, gallons) in value">...</div></div>``` with vue to get the output you need. You would need to define dogTypes as a prop and then parse the array in the mounted callback, or make dogTypes a computed property and take it from there.

Comment: I had to mess around with this a little bit (due to my data), but reconstructing the strings into arrays did the trick to be able to access them and start generating the table. Would you be able to give me some guidance on how to build the table itself or is that outside your purview? I'm running into issues trying to group by on the table. If that's getting too close to consulting a specific question I understand. I've marked the answer as correct. Thanks!

Comment: What issue are you running into?

Comment: I was able to use the parsestring function to get an array from the strings. What I wasn't able to do was get the object like you have shown with the "levels" by dogType. My data is very similar to what I have in the question but is a couple levels further down the json, so it's inside of some other for of loops. When I tried to add the second arrow function I kept getting an error stating that I was trying to map undefined. I was able to the use parsestring function inside a for of loop on the string to get an array of value, key pairs from the data, just not the structured hierarchy you have

Answer (score -1):

Is your table example illustrative or is it meant to represent your sample data?

Your table does not seem to tally with the sample data so I am in doubt as to whether my understanding is correct?

If I can start with a generalised answer - which may not be enough but it may head you in the right direction~
1. If you can parse the data in full before seeking to output your results then you can build a summary array which makes your 'un-ordered' input data trivial - then presentation becomes a separate step.
2. If you have to do it in one pass - then you would normally think about sorting the data first - on the input - this is so you can handle *mutt's* appearing at non-contiguous points.

Make sense?

My personal preference would be to build your running totals into a separate data structure - whether you have scenario 1 or 2 so that you can trap the increment no matter what level you find your relevant keys at within the for-in.

In short - is there any conceptual problem with building a new object for your summary?

Comment: Hi Cammi, apologies, I had added the data and then modified it but have updated the json.

Comment: Super. I was heading in the same direction as @Shitiz Garg below - where you then have your Dog Type as the key of your resulting structure. The only implementation issue after this is whether you do the updates as you first parse the data, or whether you do one summary step at the end. You could also use a regex for the handling of the key instead of the object split method below (but that's preference rather than a right or wrong). Good luck.